# how to pass the value returned by the fixture as a parameter to the function

Tags: python, automated-tests, command-line-interface, pytest

I run the test like this:

```
pytest -v testing.py --parameters=10,11,12
```

inside the fixture, I get the command line arguments, make a `list` from the `string`, and I need to pass this `list` to the test as shown in the picture

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/helu8.png)

```
#  content of conftest.py
import pytest


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--parameters", action="store", default='10,11,12', help="help")


@pytest.fixture
def cmdopt(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--parameters")


#  content of testing.py
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def get_params(cmdopt):
    data = cmdopt.split(',')  #  default ['10','11','12']
    return data


@pytest.mark.parametrize('parameter', 'the list that returned the fixture get_params')
def test_mytest(parameter):
    print(parameter)  # I first expect 10 then 11 then 12
```

How can this be implemented? Thank.

Comment: Please don't post images of your code or links to images, as images are not searchable and this makes it hard to understand your question once the image target gets removed, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374700/why-do-people-post-code-as-images for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As quoted [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example):

> Sometimes you may want to implement your own parametrization scheme or
>   implement some dynamism for determining the parameters or scope of a
>   fixture. For this, you can use the **pytest_generate_tests** hook which is
>   called when collecting a test function. Through the passed in metafunc
>   object you can inspect the requesting test context and, most
>   importantly, you can call metafunc.parametrize() to cause
>   parametrization.

So, check this out:

```
#  content of conftest.py
import pytest


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--parameters", action="store", default='10,11,12', help="help")


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
if 'parameters' in metafunc.fixturenames:
    if metafunc.config.getoption('parameters'):
        option_value = metafunc.config.getoption('parameters')
        metafunc.parametrize("parameters", option_value.split(','))

#  content of testing.py
import pytest


def test_mytest(parameter):
    print(parameter)
```

Comment: option_value = metafunc.config.option.jobs
E   AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'jobs'

Comment: That's how it worked:

 import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--parameters", action="store", default='10,11,12', help="help")

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'parameters' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        out = metafunc.config.getoption('parameters')
        metafunc.parametrize("parameters", [i for i in out[0].split(',')])